# Printing input from TextField to a Label in Xcode with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working on a simple guessing game app, just to get more comfortable with Swift and Xcode. I have been able to input within userInput and get it to print a message to the console, however when I try to get it to print my input to usersGuess(which is a label), I can not figure it out.

Here's my code within a single view application via Xcode:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var correctAnswerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usersGuess: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        correctAnswerLabel.text = "Changes when the button is pressed."
    }

    @IBAction func userInput(sender: UITextField) {
        println("This is working")
    }


}
```

I'm sure this is simple, but I am scratching my head lol.

Comment: Looking at your code, I can't see anything wrong with it. So my best bet is that you check if `correctAnswerLabel` has actually been wired (see the little dot on the left of that line, is it filled?). Also make sure that you have connected the target-action properly for this `buttonPressed` action. And double check if the label is actually shown on the screen (you might set the background color to orange or green for easier inspection).

Answer (score 4):

```
@IBAction func userInput(sender: UITextField) {
    println("This is working")
    usersGuess.text = sender.text
}
```

Comment: I know it might be against SOF's rule, but how to mix up two different outputs to the console, like in java:
System.out.println("The entered age is: " + age);
In xcode:
print("entered age is: " * age.text)

Comment: For Swift I use: print("The text is: \\(sender.text)"). Haven't tried your example.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am still new to iOS dev and Swift, I think you could also take a look at the use of delegate in this [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1) Apple provides. I guess it might be the code didn't resign your text field's first-responder status. Hence, the `usersGuess` could not update. (Anyone who knows how this work please leave a comment.)

To do this, basically

- Create an outlet for the `UITextField` that receives user's input, say, `usersInput`.
- Set `ViewController` as a delegate of `usersInput`, which will
- Resign the first-responder status of `usersInput` when the Return button on the keyboard is pressed.
- Update the text of `usersGuess`.

Code here:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var correctAnswerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usersGuess: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usersInput: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Set ViewController as a delegate
        usersInput.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Here are the callback functions for usersInput
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        usersGuess.text = textField.text
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        correctAnswerLabel.text = "Changes when the button is pressed."
    }

    @IBAction func userInput(sender: UITextField) {
        println("This is working")
    }

}
```