# Change Text of Label while editing textfield

Tags: swift, label, textfield

I tried to have a "live"! update of the text typed in the textfield in a label. I tried to do this with the text fielddidchange function, but I had no success.  I did set the textfield.delegate = self in the view did load and I read about adding something to call the field did change function.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing input from TextField to a Label in Xcode with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083943/printing-input-from-textfield-to-a-label-in-xcode-with-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it now with another method: and the biggest problem was, my label was just to small for showing all the text input.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    schaftLabel.text = schaftText.text
    return true
}
```